# How to unit test an if-else statement in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I want to test whether the if-else statements are executed,
The "if" block returns the item from the dictionary/cache and returns the output, while "else" block adds the input inside the cache and returns an output

An interface of IModifyBehavior with a method Apply

I have this classes:

```
namespace Decorator
{
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reverse Behavior
    /// </summary>
    public class ReverseBehavior : IModifyBehavior
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Applies the specified value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <returns>result</returns>
        public string Apply(string value)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            if (value != null)
            {
                char[] letters = value.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(letters);
                result = new string(letters); 
            }

            return result; 
        }
    }
}




using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Caching Decorator
    /// </summary>
    public class CachingDecorator : IModifyBehavior
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The behavior
        /// </summary>
        private IModifyBehavior behavior;


        public CachingDecorator(IModifyBehavior behavior)
        {
            if (behavior == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("behavior");
            }

            this.behavior = behavior;
        }



        private static Dictionary<string, string> cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies the specified value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// value
        /// </returns>
        public string Apply(string value)
        {
            ////Key = original value, Value = Reversed
            var result = string.Empty;

            //cache.Add("randel", "lednar");
            if(cache.ContainsKey(value))
            {
                result = cache[value];
            }
            else
            {
                result = this.behavior.Apply(value);// = "reversed";
                ////Note:Add(key,value)
                cache.Add(value, result); 
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my current code for the test, the codes were able to passed the test, but I'm not sure if my implementation was correct:

```
[TestClass]
    public class CachingDecoratorTest
    {
        private IModifyBehavior behavior;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            this.behavior = new CachingDecorator(new ReverseBehavior());
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            this.behavior = null;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Apply_Cached_ReturnsReversedCachedValue()
        {
            string actual = "randel";           
            ////store it inside the cache
            string cached = this.behavior.Apply(actual);

            ////call the function again, to test the else block statement
            ////Implement DRY principle next time
            string expected = this.behavior.Apply(actual);
            Assert.IsTrue(cached.Equals(expected));

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Apply_NotCached_ReturnsReversed()
        {
            string actual = "randel";
            string expected = "lednar";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, this.behavior.Apply(actual));
        }


    }
```

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would actually test the two clases in isolation, as proper units.
Below I wrote up how I would test these. For this I'm using NUnit, and [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) (available in Nuget) as a mocking framework. But you can just change the test attributes and use MSTest instead.

For the reverse behavior I'm covering both a regular apply and applying to a null text:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Decorator;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackOverflow.Tests.HowToTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ReverseBehaviorTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Apply()
        {
            const string someText = "someText";
            var target = new ReverseBehavior();
            var result = target.Apply(someText);
            Assert.AreEqual(someText.Reverse(), result);
        }
        [Test]
        public void Apply_WhenNull()
        {
            var target = new ReverseBehavior();
            var result = target.Apply(null);
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Empty, result);
        }
    }
}
```

And for the CachingDecorator, the constructor's exception throwing, applying with caching and without:

```
using System;
using Decorator;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackOverflow.Tests.HowToTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CachingDecoratorTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Constructor()
        {
            Assert.Throws(typeof(ArgumentNullException), () => new CachingDecorator(null));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Apply_NotCached()
        {
            var internalBehaviorMock = new Mock<IModifyBehavior>();
            internalBehaviorMock.Setup(x => x.Apply(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(y => y);
            const string someText = "someText";
            var target = new CachingDecorator(internalBehaviorMock.Object);
            target.Apply(someText);
            internalBehaviorMock.Verify(x => x.Apply(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
        }

        [Test]
        public void Apply_Cached()
        {
            var internalBehaviorMock = new Mock<IModifyBehavior>();
            internalBehaviorMock.Setup(x => x.Apply(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(y => y);
            const string someOtherText = "someOtherText";
            var target = new CachingDecorator(internalBehaviorMock.Object);
            target.Apply(someOtherText);
            target.Apply(someOtherText);
            internalBehaviorMock.Verify(x => x.Apply(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use a mocking framework (like Moq, for instance) to create a fake `IModifyBehaviour` object.

The `Apply_NotCached_ReturnsReversed` test would then verify that the `Apply` method of the mock object was called to generate the result.  The `Apply_Cached_ReturnsReversedCachedValue` test would check that the result was returned without calling the `Apply` method of the mock object.

As it is, you test for the cached case doesn't actually prove that the result came from the cache.

Comment: Sir will it be ok if just create a stubclass that inherits from the class that I'm trying to test then modify the if-else that returns something like "if was reached" for if, and "else was reached" for the else block?

Comment: No, because then you're not testing the actual method that you're wanting to test.

Answer (score 0):

just try to set cache dictionary values in your testcase and check for count after calling Apply(string value) method.

```
` 
       public void Apply_Cached_ReturnsReversedCachedValue()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> cacheDict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "sometext", "txetemos" } };

            string str = "sometext";

            int dictionaryCountBeforeApply = cacheDict.Count();

            //set value to static cache field using reflection, here dictionary count is 1
            Type type = typeof(CachingDecorator);
            FieldInfo cacheFieldInfo = type.GetField("cache", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            cacheFieldInfo.SetValue(decorator, cacheDict);

            string result = decorator.Apply(str);

            int dictionaryCountAfterApply = cacheDict.Count();

            Assert.AreEqual(dictionaryCountAfterApply, dictionaryCountBeforeApply);
        }


        public void Apply_NotCached_ReturnsReversed()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> cacheDict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { };
            string str = "sometext";

            int dictionaryCountBeforeApply = cacheDict.Count();

            //set value to static cache field using reflection, here dictionary count is 0
            Type type = typeof(CachingDecorator);
            FieldInfo cacheFieldInfo = type.GetField("cache", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            cacheFieldInfo.SetValue(decorator, cacheDict);

            string result = decorator.Apply(str);

            int dictionaryCountAfterApply = cacheDict.Count();

            Assert.AreNotEqual(dictionaryCountAfterApply, dictionaryCountBeforeApply);
        }`
```